# Combining map and length in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I have two problems both of them with using map and length
The first one should give me back the word count but instead it only count the elements in the list.

```
countWords :: [String]-> Int
countWords xs = length (map (words) xs)

countWords ["asd  qwe", "-- Foo", "", "\thello world "] => 4--instead it have six words
```

The second is trickier because it should give back one int for the whole list. I can only count the characters of the individual elements, not the whole.

```
countChars :: [String]-> [Int] --it should be Int
countChars xs = map (\w -> length (w)) xs 

countChars ["asd  qwe", "-- Foo", "", "\thello world "] => [8,6,0,13]--it should give back the sum of this list which is 27
```

Comment: Can you give some example data, what you expect to get, and why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: For the second one, you could simply call sum on the result

Comment: 1. Find out what `map words ["asd  qwe"]` returns. Is this what you want? Is the *type* of the result OK? 2. How is the desired result of `countChars` related to the actual result? What is missing to transform one to the other?

Comment: Words ["asd qwe"] should give back 2. My problem is that I can't iterate trough the list to count the words in each element and at the end sum these numbers. CountChars already knew this but I want give back one integer which is the sum of the resulting numbers.

Comment: 1. `Words ["asd qwe"] should give back 2` I have asked you to figure out what it *does*, not what it *should do*. (And if it *should* return 2, what `length 2` is supposed to do then?) 2. Of course you can find a sum of numbers in a list. You just cannot use `map` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second one, you just need to call `sum` on the result.

```
countChars xs = sum (map (\w -> length (w)) xs)
```

which can also be rewritten as

```
countChars xs = sum $ map length xs
```

For the first one, we'll have to calculate the number of words in each element, and finally sum the result.

`words` will give you a list of the words, so after doing `map (words) xs` (no need to have parentheses around words btw), you'll get the following:

```
map words ["asd  qwe", "-- Foo", "", "\thello world "] 
=> 
[["asd","qwe"],["--","Foo"],[],["hello","world"]]
```

The first thing you want to do is to get the length of each sublist, which you could fit into your `map`

```
map (\x -> length (words x)) xs
```

Now, the result is:

```
[2,2,0,2]
```

And by running sum on the result, you get 6. So the end result is

```
countWords :: [String]-> Int
countWords xs = sum $ map (\x -> length (words x)) xs
```

With some syntax sugar, you could do the following, but I find that most beginners are confused by it:

```
countWords xs = sum $ map (length . words) xs
```

or even better

```
countWords = sum . map (length . words)
```